# why cant vcredist_x86.exe installed quietly?

Tags: visual-c++, installation

I need to install vcredist_x86.exe (Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package) quietly. I entered "vcredist_x86.exe /q" on cmd.exe. However, vcredist_x86 didn't install successfully. I used Task Manager to inspect what happened. I found out that a process named "msiexec.exe" keeps alive until you kill it.

Comment: It does take a while to run, how long did you wait?  Also, the `msiexec.exe` is the actual installation app.

Answer (score 9):

VC++ 2005 is made with older version so arguments /q (/qb) or /passive /norestart will not work (mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/10/20/10078468.aspx).

For quiet mode use **/Q** switch, to get all parameters run `vcredist_86.exe /?`

Answer (score 0):

To silently install the VC redist, merge the vc redist MSM into your own App's MSI and avoid the need to run a separate EXE at all.

Martyn

PS: Don't kill msiexec. You'll get your machine into a bad state.

Comment: He's talking about if you're writing an installer for an application that you developed, and you're including `vcredist_x86.exe` as part of your application's installer. Not likely to be your situation based on your question.