# Converting msiexec command from cmd to powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-installer

In my `powershell` script, I need to run couple of `msiexec` commands quietly. The problem is when I try to run the command, the Windows Installer help popup shows rather than executing the command. (Below Image)

[image]

The same command runs well in cmd. Below is my command. I have kept the `&` in the command in double quotes to consider it as a string as suggested.

```
& msiexec /log c:\msxml.log /quiet /I "&" D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\prerequisites\msxml6\msxml6_x64.msi
```

I tried using `Start-Process -FilePath` to run this but end up with the below error.

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'c:\msxml.log'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath msiexec /log c:\msxml.log /quiet /I "&" D:\Lo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Can someone provide an details on how to execute the command quietly using powershell.

Comment: Just get rid of the "&" and the & at the start so :: msiexec /log c:\msxml.log /quiet /I D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\prerequisites\msxml6\msxml6_x64.msi

Comment: Thanks Owain. it worked after removing both the &. But one last `msiexec` is stilling giving the Windows Installer  popup. The command looks like below - `& msiexec /i "& D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\HP_LoadGenerator.msi" /qb /l*vx "& D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\Logs\InstallationLogs"+"_"+(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-s")+".txt"` i tried removing all the & but still the same. can you help me here.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Please see my answer below for some links to [**the Windows Installer PowerShell Module**](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second command:

```
& msiexec /i "& D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\HP_LoadGenerator.msi" /qb /l*vx "& D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\Logs\InstallationLogs"+"_"+(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-s")+".txt"
```

You have two options, either set the log path to a variable or just bracket the path:

## 1 - Set to variable

```
$logfile = "D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\Logs\InstallationLogs" + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-s") + ".txt"
msiexec /i "D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\HP_LoadGenerator.msi" /qb /l*vx $logfile
```

## 2 - Bracket the path

```
msiexec /i "D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\HP_LoadGenerator.msi" /qb /l*vx ("D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\Logs\InstallationLogs" + "_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-s") + ".txt")
```

I am assuming that the command is just not evaluating the log path before running the command.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just tried just giving a static file name and it worked. Thanks for the help Owain. I'll use any of the above option and set the file name.

Comment: Owain - one query - the command `& D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\prerequisites\vc2005sp1_mfc_security_update_x86\vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn"" "` is getting executed without any errors but it's not getting installed. When i run the same in cmd, its executing and installing. is the `msiexec` in the command making it to not execute in PS ? please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I want to alert you to the [**Windows Installer PowerShell Module**](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi) on github.com. Scroll down on this front page for description and some samples, **[see releases tab for download](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi/releases)**. I haven't really tested it much, but it is from [Heath Stewart](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/) - Microsoft Senior Software Engineer ([github](https://github.com/heaths)).

***Brief, inline sample***:

```ps
install-msiproduct .\example.msi -destination (join-path $env:ProgramFiles Example)
```

---

***Some Additional Links***:

- [How can I use powershell to run through an installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221983/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-run-through-an-installer/46224987#46224987)
- [Get the Windows Installer PowerShell Module easier with WMF 5.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/12/18/get-the-windows-installer-powershell-module-easier-with-wmf-5-0/)

Comment: thanks, will look into it. if you can help me on this command.. `D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\prerequisites\vc2005sp1_mfc_security_update_x86\vcredist_x86.exe /q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn"" "` is perfectly working in cmd but not in powershell. i have a similar command (2008 inplace of 2005 in the command) which is running fine both in cmd and PS. not sure what am i missing here.

Comment: Not familiar with this, but why don't you run `vcredist_x86.exe` directly in silent mode as explained when you do `vcredist_x86.exe /?` and get the command line options? Not sure you need to deal with the MSI at all.

Comment: I tried with `D:\LoadGeneratorsetup\prerequisites\vc2005sp1_mfc_security_update_x86\vcredist_x86.exe /quiet /norestart` but it says "command line option syntax error" so it is looking for parameters

Comment: Sorry, can't investigate this right now. [Maybe have a quick look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985961/why-cant-vcredist-x86-exe-installed-quietly/17341974).

Comment: Great. The convention is to create a new question for largely unrelated "follow-up" questions - maybe consider that for the future - there is a lot of moderation here on SO. Glad that simple link helped though!