# How to pass arguments to MSI file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, arguments, windows-installer

I've read that you can pass arguments to a .msi file, but I have no idea how to do it correctly. I've tried the following, where `$ArgumentList` is an array.

```
$ArgumentList = @("/i .\NSClient v67.msi", "/norestart", "/quiet", "/l*v '$directory'", "token=$token", "host=$_host", "mode=$mode")
Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

This is part of my script, where I'm trying to install NetSkope on my machine by executing a command.
In theory, the command should look like `msiexec /i "NSClient v67.msi" token=loremipsum host=bryan.goskope.com mode=peruserconfig /norestart /quiet /l*v "C:\Temp\NetskopeInstallation.log`.

```
#Find file path
$rawPath = Invoke-Expression -Command 'C:\Windows\System32\WHERE /r C:\Users\ /f NSClient*.msi'

#Extract the directory
$filePath = Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe --% /c FOR /f ""tokens=1"" %A IN ($rawPath) DO (ECHO 
'%~dpA')"

#Cast $filePath to work with string methods
$filePath = Out-String -InputObject $filePath
$filePath = $filePath.split("'")[1]

Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe --% /c cd $filePath"


$ArgumentList = @("/i .\NSClient v67.msi", "/norestart", "/quiet", "/l*v '$directory'", 
"token=$token", "host=$_host", "mode=$mode")
Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: Please check this: [PowerShell MSI Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58141208/129130) and [secondary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130). Please check the different links contained in these two base answers, there are links to what you directly ask as well. Direct link to github.com: https://github.com/heaths/psmsi

Comment: I would use Heath's module as Stein mentions. I would also rename your MSI and remove the space to avoid that one more issue with debugging. Once you've got it working you can always put the space back.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using the [Powershell MSI Module](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi)
Concerning [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-5.0):
`-Argumentlist` expects string as a type. I don't think you can just pass an array.
You also need to surround the parameters that require a space with escaped double quotes. The escape character is powershell is the grave-accent(`).
Another problem is that the variable $directory will never be expanded, because it is surrounded with single quotes. You need to remove those.
The following should work for your example, but I personally would just remove the space in the file name, since you don't need to do weird stuff with escaping.

Without escaping:

```
$ArgumentList = "/i .\NSClientv67.msi /norestart /quiet /l*v $directory token=$token host=$_host mode=$mode"
```

With escaping:

```
$ArgumentList = "/i `".\NSClient v67.msi`" /norestart /quiet /l*v $directory token=$token host=$_host mode=$mode"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different syntax:

```
$MSIArguments = @(
    "/x"
    "`"C:\path with spaces\test.msi`""
    "/qb"
    "/norestart"
    "/l*v"
    "`"C:\path with spaces\test.log`""
)

Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MSIArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
```