# Is there a way to accept the license agreement to a silent installation of a .msi file using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-installer, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to quietly install a .msi file using C# without the need for any user input. I'm having trouble trying to get past the license agreement so that the installation can continue. Is there a way to pass an argument so that the agreement is accepted without any user imput?

Answer (score 3):

***Caution***: I would avoid triggering software installation from within an application binary - *unless you are making an actual setup launcher application*. It can work, but it may trigger serious problems with anti-virus and malware scanners. I have seen that before. I would assume you would also need to run elevated - with **admin rights** - to kick off your installs (per-machine installations).

---

***Some digressions and suggestions first***: MSI can be installed via **`msiexec.exe commands`**, [**`Powershell`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58141208/129130), **`DTF C#`** (see below), **`WMI`**, **`MSI API`** (**`COM`**, **`Win32`**).

***Batch***: With that said, why don't you just install using a regular batch file? The /QN switch will bypass the entire setup GUI-sequence and then there should be no need to accept any license agreements. [MSI logging information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130) (short version: open log and search for "value 3" to find errors).

This command must be run from an elevated command prompt (admin rights):

```
msiexec.exe /I "Installer.msi" /QN /L* "C:\msilog.log" ALLUSERS=1
```

***Setup.exe***: You can also make a [WiX Burn bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071758/129130) (see link for code mockup) or use some sort of other tool to make a `setup.exe` that will install your original application and then other components in sequence - so there is nothing to trigger to install from the application.

***Interactive Install***: If you want to install with some user interaction you can locate the property controlling the accept status of the license agreement and set that to the appropriate value - usually 1 - to indicate accepted license.

---

***DTF***: Now the code answer. There is a component installed with the [WiX toolkit](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/) called **`DTF - Desktop Tools Foundation`** It has a number of C# classes designed to deal with MSI files via managed code. [**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1061606/129130) explains what file to add as a reference in Visual Studio and describes the different files / assemblies of DTF briefly. [Another DTF sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225970/129130).

The relevant file for your described purpose is: **`"Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"`**.

***NOTE!***

1. **`You must launch Visual Studio with admin rights to install per machine`**.
2. Add project reference to `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"`.

The below code tested in VS2017 ([a more elaborate version with admin check here](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/DTFInstallMSI2/DTFInstallMSI2/Program.cs) - [zipped](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/DTFInstallMSI2.zip)):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

// RUN WITH ADMIN RIGHTS

namespace DTFTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Silent);
                Installer.EnableLog(InstallLogModes.Verbose, @"E:\Install.log");
                Installer.InstallProduct(@"E:\Install.msi", "");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:\n\n " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Link***:

- [On reboot initiated issues](https://github.com/jennings/Causal/blob/d0fc2374d2b48ba7d1f595e3a2960480df2a3c36/src/Causal.Updater/Updates/MsiUpdateRunner.cs)
- [Install via VBScript COM, DTF, Win32](https://serverfault.com/questions/577969/is-it-possible-to-disable-msiexec-help-gui/596519#596519)

Answer (score 1):

Generally you just run the msi silently like

msiexec /i foo.msi /qn

If the MSI has implemented an additional consent you might have to pass a property like

msiexec /i foo.msi /qn ACCEPTEULA=1

The exact name of this property would depend on the MSI so you'd need to consult vendor documentation or examine the MSI using a tool such as ORCA.

Comment: Thanks! But what if the property I need to change is private? I can't change it on CMD.

Comment: Create a transform and change the behavior so you can.